# Draw transparent Gtk.Window

Tags: gtk, go, cairo

I'm trying to make a transparent GTK window to draw on; however, I can't seem to figure out how to implement this with Go using [go-cairo](https://github.com/ungerik/go-cairo) and [go-gtk](https://github.com/mattn/go-gtk/). Does anyone know how this can be accomplished?

Answer (score 2):

go-gtk doesn't have any window opacity functionality yet, making the task impossible unless you implement them yourself. This is evidenced by lines [1392](https://github.com/mattn/go-gtk/blob/master/gtk/gtk.go#L1392) and [1393](https://github.com/mattn/go-gtk/blob/master/gtk/gtk.go#L1393) of gtk.go.

As for go-cairo(which I haven't personally used) if you look at [this](https://github.com/ungerik/go-cairo/blob/master/surface.go#L109), you'll see the functionality that is compatible with [this](http://zetcode.com/gfx/cairo/transparency/). The Go function in questions is:

```
func (self *Surface) SetSourceRGBA(red, green, blue, alpha float64) {
    C.cairo_set_source_rgba(self.context, C.double(red), C.double(green), C.double(blue), C.double(alpha))
}
```

which is the wrapper for cairo_set_source_rgba. A C-based example of this in action is available through [plan99.net](http://plan99.net/~mike/files/alphademo.c).

I would say that playing with alpha channels in go-cairo is the best bet right now to get the desired effect.

Comment: Thank you for your response. After looking at the resources to which you linked, I'm still a little confused about how to get go-cairo to paint transparently on the Gtk Window's surface in such a way that it renders the window transparent.

Comment: @weberc2 Did you ever figure this out?  I think I'm having the same issue in which I have a DrawingArea on a background image and wish for the drawing area to be transparent except where it is drawn on.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson No, I haven't figured it out yet. I temporarily gave  up to focus on other projects that can give me a better understanding of go-gtk and go-cairo. Can you contact me about the specifics of your application?

Comment: @weberc2 Specifically, I have a `DrawingArea` which is an animation using Cairo.   The Cairo animation is a minority of the area at any one time, so I would like to have the area not drawn via Cairo to be transparent showing the background image.  I'm not sure it matters but the DrawingArea and background `Image` are both contained inside a `Fixed` widget.